# How important is it to learn latex?

Tags: soft-question, advice

So I am currently in my senior year (Undergraduate mathematics). And I am thinking to continue on and do my masters and PHD in mathematics. I need to now how important it is to learn latex and how often will I get to use it as a graduate student in Mathematics. I noticed it is not very important in my undergraduate studies because I am not publishing papers but of course when I do my graduate studies , it's all about research and publishing papers. I saw many people in this website asking graduate level questions and their latex skills are not very good and sometimes I can't even read the question until someone edits it.

Also I didn't see any course in any undergraduate math degree that teaches how to use latex so is it a self learning skill? So any graduate school will just assume that you know how to use latex?

I am assuming anyone doing a graduate degree has enough motivation to learn many skills on his own. Does that include learning latex ?

Also I need to know , did anyone have any difficulty in his graduate studies because he wasn't that good in latex ?

A final question, if latex is pretty important for mathematicians, why just not include a course in all universities that teaches how to use latex, even forcing the students to submit their assignments using latex?

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate if you had asked such question in Latex section of SE

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate to ask at Academia S.E..

Comment: I just want to hear the opinions from the mathematicians here !!

Comment: In my honest opinion, this is a non-issue. You do need to learn $\LaTeX$ eventually, but it's not that big a challenge that you should worry about it. It's just something you do like eating and showering.

Comment: If you can finish a MSc or even a PhD in math, then you can learn LaTeX in one afternoon.

Comment: At my university there are two LaTeX courses, one for the humanities and one for mathematics and computer science (I deliver the latter). They're not mandatory, though. As a mathematician, you definitely should learn it: look at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latexresources.html for some good guides in English.

Comment: [Good LaTeX resource](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), if you want

Comment: You should learn $\LaTeX$, definitely. And, it isnt really difficult, so you learn it in a couple of hours.  Do it now, so you free yourself from agonizing over word or such programs!

Comment: You will definitely want it eventually: mine is pretty nearly the last generation of mathematicians that could get by without it, and I’m $67$ and retired. But as others have said, it’s not hard to learn the basics; all of what I know I’ve picked up since I retired by reading and writing answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a point of reference, every HW assignment I did in graduate school I typeset with Latex.  This wasn't required, but it helped for a number of reasons.  First, it is more difficult to draw pictures when you use latex.  This makes you think twice before attempting to argue-by-picture... in my opinion, that is a big plus.  Second, at my school at least, it was required (whether you were in mathematics or not) that your thesis/dissertation be typeset using latex.  (So it was required to learn at least enough to do basic typesetting.)  Third, knowing latex makes it possible to write research papers.  Many journals will take other formats, but many do not.

Comment: I completely agree, specially on thinking twice when it comes to graphics. +1

Comment: Figures are no problem in TeX. Draw them with any graphics program and import them into your TeX-document as eps- or pdf-file with some special command.

Comment: I still draw figures periodically; I like tikz/pgf a lot.  It just takes a little more forethought when creating the figures than "scribbling down" something with pen/paper.  I don't mean to imply that pictures are bad, just that they should illustrate an argument not "be" the argument.

Comment: @TravisJ. I've heard that it doesnt matter in scientific community if you use Word or  Latex for writing a report or anything else. Is that True?

Comment: @mehrdad, it probably depends on the specific community.  If you write a math paper in word it will be really hard to find people who will take it seriously.  Others communities I'm less familiar with.  I know many CS conferences and bio-journals will accept submissions word format, but they tend to look much less professional in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that if you can finish a MSc or even a PhD in math, then you can learn the basics of LaTeX in one afternoon.  Also, it seems you have used LaTeX in other questions on this site.  Just keep going and learn whatever you need for the current project.  From time to time read a tutorial to get inspired.